# forEach parallel on IntStream.range() gives wrong answer

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

```
public int getAllCandidatesUsing8(int num) {
    final int[] cnt = {0};
    int pow = (int) Math.pow(2, num);
    IntStream.range(0, pow).parallel()
            .forEach(i -> {
                //computing codes
                cnt[0]++;
            });
    return cnt[0];
}
```

Above code is a small part of my codes to show the problem.

I ran the method with input of number 8 but got wrong answer like 63, 61, 62 not always 64 which is the right answer.

If I'm not using parallel, it works correctly.
(btw, I use parallel because the input is quite large: num might be hundreds)

Why?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do here? You could just do `return pow` and not use Stream at all.

Comment: I have lots in ////computing codes algorithm

Comment: I found my algorithm in side the //computing codes not executed correctly, then I create this method to show my problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition `cnt[0]++;` is not atomic operation. `cnt[0] = cnt[0] + 1;` needs to do 3 things: (1) read current value of `cnt[0]`; (2) calculate `cnt[0] + 1`; (3) assign result back to `cnt[0]`. Between each of these operations other threads can do their own set of this 3 operations. So what do you think happens when thread A and B will be executed in order: 1A, 1B, 2A, 3A, 2B, 3B?

Comment: Thanks @Pshemo, the result will be lower than expected. I understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `cnt[0]++;` is [not an atomic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25168062/1743880), so it is not thread-safe.

Without seeing the other part of your code, you could use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead and use [`incrementAndGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--).

However, I strongly suggest that you refactor your code, maybe even drop the use of Streams. Mutating external variables is not a good practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Access to array cnt is not synchronized, so the ++ operations may overlap. Some of them therefore cancel each other out.

Try using separate indices for each iteration, or a synchronized variable of type AtomicInteger.