# How can I assign a unique sequential number to each instance of a class?

Tags: java

I have two classes:

---

```
public class Worker{

  String name;

  private static int count=0;

  public Worker(String N){

     name=N;
     count++;
  }

  public String numberOfTime(){
      return name +", "+ count; 
  }
}
```

---

```
public class counting{

   public static void main(String[]args){
       Worker worker1 = new Worker("Jack");

       Worker worker2 = new Worker("John");

       System.out.println(worker1.numberOfTime());

       System.out.println(worker2.numberOfTime());
   }
}
```

---

While I want to get (Jack, 1) and (John, 2) and so on, it prints (Jack, 2) and (John, 2).

Can anyone explain me how to change this?

Thanks.

Comment: Static variables belong to the class object, not instances.

Comment: Why "John 2"? It is called only one time for "John"

Comment: I want to give each worker a number. The first worker  would be number 1, while the last one would be number n. Here however it gives me the number of time the method has been called ( always i).

Comment: @lezaza That is not counting!

Comment: @lezaza Why do you expect (Jack, 2)?

Comment: What you Need is an other class, that is generating the id

Comment: I think you need to change the title of this question as it is completely misleading.

Comment: The output you're trying to print makes not sense, please explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Rename your variable and method names, because they are missleading. also read about naming conventions. Class names should start with uppercase character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Worker{

  String name;
  int number;

  private static int totalCount=0;


  public Worker(String N){

     name=N;
     totalCount++;
     number = totalCount;
  }

  public String numberOfTime(){
      return name +", "+ number; 
  }
}
```

Try this

You are not assigning a number to the instances, Their total count should be separate from the number assigned to every instance

Comment: typo :), Fixed it

Comment: You could declare number as `int number = totalCount++;`

Comment: @MostafaEl-Messiry don't ask specificly for your answer to be accepted but remember OP to mark the most fitted one ;)

Comment: @AxelH Hehe. [You might find this a good read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an ID to each Worker, you should so something like this:

```
public class Worker{

  String name;

  private static int count=0;

  private int id = ++count;

  public Worker(String N){
     name=N;
  }

  public String numberOfTime(){
      return name +", "+ id; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way for me is to introduce an IdGenerator as an extra class.

```
public class IdGenerator {

    private static int id =1;

    public static int newId(){
        return id++;
    }
}
```

and Change your `Worker` class to:

```
public class Worker{

  String name;

  private  int id=0;

  public Worker(String n){

     name=n;
     id = IdGenerator.newId();
  }

  public String numberOfTime(){
      return name +", "+ id; 
  }
}
```

It is better OO design than integrating the Counter in the object itself.