# Unsynchronized method producing consistent results

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm new to Java and playing around with threads. I wrote this small program to check what happens when 3 threads are accessing an unsynchronized method:

```
class SharedValueHolder {
  public static int globalCounter = 0;
  public static void increment() {
    globalCounter++;
  }
}

class Incrementor implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      //reportValue();
      SharedValueHolder.increment();
    }
  }

  private void reportValue() {
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(threadName + " - " + SharedValueHolder.globalCounter);
  }
}

public class ThreadTest {
  public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    runTest();
  }

  private static void runTest() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Incrementor());
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Incrementor());
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new Incrementor());

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

    Thread.sleep(300);
    System.out.println(SharedValueHolder.globalCounter);
  }
}
```

Suprisingly, the result is almost always 15. Sometimes I do get a 14, but that's very rare.

Now if I uncomment the call to `reportValue()` in `Incrementor.run` I see something like this for example:

```
Thread-2 - 0
Thread-1 - 0
Thread-0 - 0
Thread-0 - 3
Thread-0 - 4
Thread-0 - 5
Thread-0 - 6
Thread-1 - 2
Thread-1 - 8
Thread-1 - 9
Thread-1 - 10
Thread-2 - 1
Thread-2 - 12
Thread-2 - 13
Thread-2 - 14
```

Which clearly shows that the threads "see" the same values at the same times, but still the result is correct. Could somebody explain to me how this works?

Comment: "I do get a 14, but that's very rare." - So it's **not** consistent... as expected.

Comment: How did you conclude "that the threads "see" the same values at the same times"? The output does not speak for that.

Comment: Does it not? As I said, I'm new to Java. What is a good way to verify that?

Comment: The fact that there is "1" after the "10" looks ... suspicious. I am unsure what you are asking, is it "why does it not always work" or "why does it sometimes work"?

Comment: Your numbers are too low.  Try iterating to 100000 instead of 5.  You are just finishing so quickly that the threads don't interact much.  You might also put a sleep(100) in your inner loop if you want to simulate interactions.

Comment: Yeah ok that actually explains it. Thanks @BillK increasing the numbers did actually provide consistently wrong results as expected. I guess I was expecting the numbers being in the range of 5 - 15 most of the time and was surpised I'm getting a correct result mostly.

Comment: Have you tried making the globalCounter variable volatile? I thought increment would be atomic, especially after a compiler optimization that convered it to a pre-increment

Comment: Also, using Thread.sleep() as a substitute for calling join() on the threads isn't great practice. You should deterministically join the threads back together, not rely on sleep statements

Comment: OK I take it back, x++ isn't atomic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic http://madbean.com/2003/mb2003-44/

Comment: The best fix, by the way, is probably to make globalVariable an AtomicInteger.  You could also make increment synchronized, but I believe AtomicInteger is more optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrency is not an easy topic, and one of the reasons it's tricky is because sometimes you may get a correct result (and think your code is good), but that doesn't mean the code is really correct; it means given the environment you're running it with, the number of threads... It's working just fine. But it's likely to fail in a highly concurrent environment.

Still, you say you're seeing the same result **almost always**, which makes it NOT always.

It's also the scope of your problem, with a loop of 5 elements only. Possibly the second and third thread haven't even started when the first thread finishes.

But it's easy to see it's wrong. Try running this sample instead:

```
class SharedValueHolder {
  public static int counter = 0;
}

class Incrementor implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
      SharedValueHolder.counter++;
    }
  }
}

public class ThreadTest {
  public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Incrementor());
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Incrementor());
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println(SharedValueHolder.counter);
  }
}
```

Two threads adding 100.000, so you'd expect 200.000 at the end. But instead, I get:

```
102472
105560
121472
139343
120953
```