# How to get static variable properly from multithreading class?

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say I have code like this:

---

```
class A extends Thread {
    Thread t = new Thread();
    private static int id = 0;

    A(){
        id++;
        this.t.start();
    }

    private synchronized static int getId() { return id; }

    public void run() { System.out.println(getId()); }
}

public class Test throws InterruptedException {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A thread1 = new A();
        A thread2 = new A();
        try {
            thread1.t.join();
            thread2.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Main thread ends here");
    }
}
```

---

I'm expecting the output like this:

---

```
1
2
```

---

But the output is:

---

```
2
2
```

---

What should I do here? Thanks for help. Q.

Comment: `private static volatile int id = 0;`

Comment: `volatile` is not enough, `++` is not atomic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic -> use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Why does your `Thread` have a `Thread` in it? Further, never `extends Thread` - this creates all sorts of strange behaviours, use a `Runnable`. You never start your `A` instances; you start an internal `Thread` that does nothing. You increment the variable in the ctor not in the `run()` method. This code is wrong in almost every way - please start by reading a basic tutorial on threads in Java.

Comment: Thanks, I have to work it out. Q.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. The method getId is defined in the class Thread and it returns a long, not an int.

Comment: Forgot about static in method declaration

Answer (score 2):

For this case, you should use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of int, and change methods.

```
public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final A thread1 = new A();
        final A thread2 = new A();
        try
        {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Main thread ends here");
    }

    public static class A extends Thread
    {
        private static final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(0);

        A()
        {
            start();
        }

        private synchronized int getID()
        {
            return id.get();
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void run()
        {
            id.incrementAndGet();
            System.out.println(getID());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you fix the messed up thread situation this does not really change anything. The original output will always be `12` anyway, since the increment happens synchronously in the ctor. (well, the original output *would* be that, right now there is no output since `run` is never executed)

Comment: Read the code more carefully - `id` is only ever mutated by the main thread. The code does not do anything remotely sensible - adding `AtomicInteger` won't fix the nonsense the OP has written.

Comment: I fixed answer to print correct numbers

Comment: @luk2302 I corrected OP class and I can post the answer if you open the question

Comment: @Spara you are out of lock, OP already agreed that the question was duplicate - the real problem he wanted to solve was that of an atomic increment, which the duplicate answers.