# How does synchronization happens under the hood in Kotlin Coroutine?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand how does coroutines access other thread's data. Just have a look on below kotlin program in which I tried to understand the `variableAccessCount` in main thread can be accessed from Coroutine C1 & Coroutine C2 however as per my understanding coroutines are piece of code which runs on different threads and in Android  threads can't be touched directly there is mechanism to do that such as Handler, in coroutine also we do have **withContext()** but specific to this example,

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.coroutines.coroutineContext

var variableAccessCount = 0

fun main() {
    println("${Thread.currentThread()}")

    GlobalScope.launch {//Coroutine C1
        println("${Thread.currentThread()}")
        firstAccess() }

    GlobalScope.launch {//Coroutine C2
        println("${Thread.currentThread()}")
        secondAcess() }

    Thread.sleep(2000L)

    print("The variable is accessed $variableAccessCount number of times")
}

suspend fun firstAccess() {
    delay(500L)
    variableAccessCount++
}

suspend fun secondAcess() {
    delay(1000L)
    variableAccessCount++
}
```

Would somebody help me to understand How does synchronization happens under the hood  for variable **var functionCalls = 0** This variable is declared in Main thread and can be accessed from both suspend functions (completeMessage & improveMessage), which are running inside coroutine but on different worker thread.

Program O/P

```
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main]
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]
The variable is accessed 2 number of times
```

Comment: It doesn't. You should be using `AtomicInteger` or `LongAdder`.

Comment: It is executing please try from above code

Comment: Yes it works. But it's not guaranteed to, you're exposing yourself to a race condition. See this answer for [Why is i++ not atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25168105/5288316). What you call "synchronization" is normally called "atomicity" and is handled by classes like the ones I mention above. Also threads may have separate execution, but they still share memory.

Comment: Understood but then with respect to your above comment, in Android, UI can’t touch UI thread from another thread

Comment: It can't but that's a limitation of the Android framework, not the JVM (or Kotlin).

Comment: Amazing dot is now connected, so can we say the answer to above question is to use atomicity and withContext to switch the thread!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `AtomicInteger`:

```kotlin
val variableAccessCount = AtomicInteger(0)

suspend fun firstAccess() {
    delay(500L)
    variableAccessCount.incrementAndGet()
}

suspend fun secondAcess() {
    delay(1000L)
    variableAccessCount.incrementAndGet()
}
```

- Thread confinement fine-grained

```kotlin
val counterContext = newSingleThreadContext("CounterContext")
var variableAccessCount = 0

suspend fun firstAccess() {
    delay(500L)
    withContext(counterContext) { variableAccessCount++ }
}

suspend fun secondAcess() {
    delay(1000L)
    withContext(counterContext) { variableAccessCount++ }
}
```

- Mutual exclusion

```kotlin
val mutex = Mutex()
var variableAccessCount = 0

suspend fun firstAccess() {
    delay(500L)
    mutex.withLock  { variableAccessCount++ }
}

suspend fun secondAcess() {
    delay(1000L)
    mutex.withLock  { variableAccessCount++ }
}
```