# Is modCount an atomic variable?

Tags: java, list, concurrency, concurrentmodification

I read that a `ConcurrentModificationException` can be thrown whenever a thread performs a structural modification upon a certain list while another thread is iterating over its elements. To detect such modification, instances of the class `List` store the number of times they were modified in a field called `modCount`, whose value is checked at each iteration of the list to check whether the latter was modified. If my understanding was correct, access to `modCount` needs to be synchronized, because if the list in question was to be modified after checking the value of `modCount` in the last iteration and before the end of the loop, the iterator would fail to detect that the list was modified during its last iteration.

Comment: What do you think is easier to understand from our perspective? The code, or a paragraph of text describing the code? Show us, don't tell us. You haven't even told us what class you're talking about. I think it's probably ArrayList, but I shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: The source code for (e.g.) ArrayList is available; it contains likes like "modCount++" which is clearly not a use of an atomic variable, nor is it in a synchronized method.

Comment: @Michael Why do you assume that there is a code? My question is purely conceptual. It concerns the inner workings of the iteration process, and does not reflect a problem with some code that I have written.

Comment: @ControlAltDel [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic)

Comment: *"My question is purely conceptual"* No it isn't. It's about a specific implementation. That's as applied as it gets. "*does not reflect a problem with some code that I have written*" That doesn't mean you can't share the parts of the code you're talking about.

Comment: @accessviolation So a list modification could take place in the last iteration after checking the value of modCount without the iterator detecting it?

Comment: @mehdicharife There is no guarantee that ConcurrentModificationException is thrown in all cases where concurrent modifications take place, no. To encounter that, one must be dealing with a non-thread safe implementation in an inherently dangerous way. In such case, the developers are basically doing you a favour by trying to detect it at all. They could not bother to detect it and open to door to whatever undefined behaviour occurs as a result.

Comment: @Michael "it's about a specific implementation" No it isn't. It's about all the implementations (instances) of the iteration process, and hence the conceptual predicate. "That doesn't mean that you can't share the parts of the code you're talking about". I'm not talking about any specific parts of code. Otherwise, I don't see the utility behind sharing a standard Java for loop. If you are unacquainted with the code of the latter, I'm not really sure you are qualified to answer my question.

Comment: "*It's about all the implementations*" No. It's about several specific implementations. 
"*I'm not talking about any specific parts of code*" >>> "*a field called modCount*"

Comment: Re, "It's about all the implementations..." It's either about the library specification, or it's about the code. There is no `modCount` in the library specification. Also of note, the [Javadoc for the `List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) says nothing whatsoever about what is supposed to happen when multiple threads access the same List. Docs for `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` only say that "If multiple threads access a linked list...it must be synchronized externally." There's no promise that an iterator will _reliably_ throw the...

Comment: ...exception if the list has been modified by a different thread than the one that is doing the iteration.

Comment: @Michael >>"It's about all the implementations" No.<<  In the full quote I say: "It's about all the implementations (instances) of the iteration process", so please learn how to read or to quote correctly. Otherwise, I can't really help you clear out your misunderstandings.  "It's about several specific implementations" You said before " It's about a specific implementation" so which is it? Being about several specific implementations is not necessarily in contradiction with being about all the implementations (instances) of the iteration process. On the contrary, the first entails the second.

Comment: @Michael The second entails the first.*

Comment: @SolomonSlow actually [`modCount` is documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractList.html#modCount) in the library specification, though `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` do not say explicitly that they are using this field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything you've said is correct, and perfectly normal.  `modCount` is not atomic, and the iterator *could* fail to detect that the list was modified, and that's fine.  Revisit the ArrayList documentation:

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. **Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis.** Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

Because `ArrayList` does not try to guarantee that it will always detect a concurrent modification, it can avoid the overhead of an atomic variable for a case that should never happen in correct code.  The use of the unsynchronized `modCount` detects the most common cases, and will sometimes (depending on exact thread ordering and the like) detect cases that are truly concurrent.  Remember, though, that `ConcurrentModificationException` almost never happens because concurrency is actually going on, but because someone calls a modification method during an iteration loop.

Comment: I probably wouldn't go as far as "almost never", but you're probably right that it's less common.

Comment: @user16320675 In a non-thread safe list? Why would it be? What do you mean "partially atomic"? That's an oxymoron

Comment: Atomicity costs more overhead in memory synchronization effort, so why should `ArrayList` bother -- again, when this should never actually happen in correct code?

Comment: @Michael: I would confidently bet 99% of CMEs encountered by developers are from single-threaded code, which I'd call close enough to "almost never."

Comment: @LouisWasserman Well, all I can say is that I'd take that bet...

Comment: @user16320675 I didn't think too hard about it, but my intuition is that whether you have an atomic write to an integer counter or not, that's probably not enough to guarantee throwing an exception in the case of concurrent read&writes. So whether atomic or not, the behaviour would be undefined either way. I think that's what you're getting at, right?

Comment: @user16320675 I suppose, the term “atomic” has been used here, because classes like `AtomicInteger` also imply memory visibility. `int` variables *are* atomic if we consider the real meaning of “atomic”. What it doesn’t have, is guarantees regarding memory visibility, but even if it had, e.g. by declaring the field `volatile`, it wouldn’t guaranty to prevent the application from inconsistencies in case of concurrent modifications. By the way, even a thread safe list doesn’t guaranty that, e.g. when iterating the `list` while `Collections.sort(list)` is done by another thread (before Java  8).