# Shared instances between threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following code :

```java
class Abs
{
    int x = 0;
    public void increment ( )
    {
        x++;
        System.out.println( x );
    }
}
```

```java
class Task1 extends Thread
{
    Abs t;
    public Task1 ( Abs x ) { t = x; }
    public void run ( ) { t.increment(); }
}
```

```java
public class Multi
{
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        Abs obj = new Abs();
        Task1 t1 = new Task1( obj );
        Task1 t2 = new Task1( obj );

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

This will make the member variable `x` of object `obj` shared between the threads `t1` and `t2`, and hence, race condition can occur resulting in the following output:

```
    2
    2
```

This is because the object `obj`  is in the heap, and hence, it is shared between the threads `t1` and `t2` ( and consequently sharing the member variable `x`).

What I am confused about is that  every thread will have an instance member `t` of class `Abs`. Now in the constructor we are assigning this instance member to the passed Abs object ( `t=x;` ). What confuses me is that since we have an instance member for every thread, this means that this instance member will be in the stack of every thread and when we assign this instance member to the passed `Abs` object, this means that every thread will have its own Abs object as they will be in the stack of the thread (because the instance member is in the stack of the thread), and therefore, the object `obj` will not be shared between the two threads t1 and t2. So how the object `obj` is actually shared between the two threads in this example?

Comment: what is your question about? you should have a look at how to ask a well-received question here.

Comment: `What I am confused about is that every thread will have an instance member t` No.  Each thread has a *reference* to the object.  A reference is like a pointer.  There's only one heap memory object of type `Abs` allocated, and the `t` "object" definitely does not appear on any thread's stack.

Comment: @catch23 Sorry I forgot to include the question.  Now I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @markspace So this means that Abs t; is just a refence to the object that will be passed to the constructor and not a variable in the stack of the thread ?  If yes , so this means that if we have declared another member variable  int x; , this means that this is also a reference to an integer and it is not a variable field in the stack of the thread ? Kindly clarify .

Comment: No, primitives like `int` are values, not references.  The value appears directly as a instance field, not a reference to a value on the heap.

Comment: There is only "one instance" of Abs  obj created, both classes t1 and t2 have been loaded with the same instance..  It is bad textbook writing, it is not a.k.a shared, simply both have access to it!(and it may ever have better functionality in that situation designed as a static class but you are probably not ready for that problem concept ,  Worse, "sharing" in that situation can easily require "asynchronous" access  handling, and that may be as heavy a concept as static with reference to "shared") The real fun starts at "volatile" keyword.

Comment: [Thread Interference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html)

Comment: Bruh, you are using the **exact same instance** in both threads. The fact that reference to that object is duplicated (or not, i dont event know), and is (or not) allocated on each thread heap does not matter as you will still use the same object a. 
Its like writing your home address on multiple sheets of paper and expecting that your house will magically clone itself so you can have N houses now:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## One object, two references

You said:

> every thread will have an instance member t of class Abs

> we have an instance member for every thread

No, not so.

Each of your two `Task1` objects holds a *reference* to an object of type `Abs`, the very same single object. You instantiated only a single `Abs` object. Then you passed a *reference* to each of the `new Task1( obj )` calls.

Knowing the difference between an [object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) (a chunk of memory) and a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) (basically, a pointer to that chunk’s location in memory) is crucial here. If you are not clear on this, [study the subject](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=java%20object%20versus%20reference&t=osx&ia=web).

Since you have only one `Abs` object in your example app, there is only one `int` primitive variable named `x`. So your code is dealing with a single number value. Each of your threads is accessing, and replacing, that value. So your code is **not thread-safe**.

See also [comment by markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75972885/shared-instances-between-threads-in-java#comment133996454_75972885).

```java
Abs obj = new Abs();          // (1) Create one single object. (2) Create a reference to that object. (3) Store that reference in a variable named `obj`.
Task1 t1 = new Task1( obj );  // Pass a *reference* to this constructor.
Task1 t2 = new Task1( obj );  // Pass a *reference* to this constructor. Happens to be the very same reference passed in line above.
// At this point, both `t1` and `t2` hold a reference leading to the same single `Abs` object. One object in memory, two references to that object.
```

[image: screenshot of two Task1 objects, but only a single Abs object]

### Race condition

The race condition occurs because  **`x++` is *not* an atomic operation**, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25168062/642706). Three separate operations occur:

- Reading `x`.
- Incrementing for a new value.
- Writing the new value back to `x`.

Being non-atomic means one thread can *read* the value of that number, and in an intervening moment, a second thread can both *read and increment* that same number, writing a new value to the `x` variable. A moment later, the first thread *increments* its previously read value, and stores that new value back into `x`. (Which threads operate in what order for however amount of time between pauses is completely unpredictable!)

So both threads can read a value of `1`. And both threads can increment that value to `2`. The **value `2` can be written *twice***, once by each of the two threads.

The lesson to learn in concurrency is that  **any mutable resource shared across threads must be protected**. (Simple in concept, tricky in practice.)

### `AtomicInteger`

In your case, one simple way to add that protection is to change your `int x` primitive to an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) object. The `AtomicInteger` class makes reading, writing, and reporting an integer value atomic.

In `Abs` class, change the declaration of `x`. And change the incrementing line `x++` to call a method on `AtomicInteger` instead.

We mark `x` as `final` to prevent any reassignment to a different `AtomicInteger` object. Reassignment would ruin the integrity of our purpose of a rolling counter.

```java
class Abs
{
    final AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger( 0 ) ;
    public void increment ( )
    {
        int newValue = x.incrementAndGet() ;
        System.out.println( newValue );
    }
}
```

A fine point on code above: We instantiate our `AtomicInteger` as part of the declaration because this guarantees per the [Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) that the code will be run *before* any other code has a chance to access this member field. Combined with `final`, we know that all threads will see and access the same single reference stored in `x` in a thread-safe manner.

---

By the way, in modern Java we rarely address the `Thread` class directly. Generally best to use the Executors framework instead.

Comment: Well described; especially from the section, **Race condition** onwards! The mention of the Executors framework makes the answer even more valuable.